# Why do blue jays eat my cat food?

Tags: food, ornithology, diet

We buy some run of the mill big-box store cat food. Over the last several weeks, I've observed a blue jay landing on the cat food dish, taking a piece or two, and flying off with it. I assumed it was eating it then, and this morning I just saw it *actually* eat a piece.

Why would a blue jay eat cat food?

**Edit**:

I just looked at the ingredient list and apparently corn is the first ingredient. But there's also "poultry by-product" and a variety of other "meats." Would the jay just smell a lot of corn or something?

Comment: It's food. It's easy to "catch". Blue jays eat insects; why not cat food?

Comment: @anongoodnurse But he says it has corn too

Comment: @TalhaIrfan - [Blue Jays are omnivorous](https://www.allaboutbirds.org/guide/blue_jay/lifehistory). Easy food is easy food.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Like other Corvids (Jays, Crows, and Ravens), Blue Jays are omnivorous and can eat and digest both animal and plant matter. Animal matter can include insects, carrion, small birds and mammals, and the eggs of other birds. Then there is plant matter including corn, seeds, etc. Your catfood was not only convenient but contains a good source of both animal and plant matter and the opportunistic tendencies of Blue Jays allowed them to take advantage.